# ORA-00911: invalid character in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am aware there are many questions related to this issue. I almost reviewed all but no suggestions could solve my problem so far. I have a query like below and this gives me ORA-00911: invalid character error.  I dont have semicolon at the end, no special characters inside the query. I could not figure out what the problem is. Any helps would be appreciated.

P.S:I am using "System.Data.OracleClient" as provider. And there is no mistake in connection string because i can make work some other queries

```
orCmd2.Connection = orConnection;
                        orCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        orCmd2.CommandText = "select distinct  p.id,
p.tn,   p.ptar, s.bno, s.pid from a.t_srtalı s,
a.V_PVIEW  p where s.id=:id and s.pid=p.pid";

orCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", pid);
 orreader2 = orCmd2.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `t_sigortalı` contains invalid character at the end.

Comment: Thx man. I spent almost 2 hours for this. The disadvantage of being turkish. You just dont realize it is a mistake cos it is a normal letter in your alphabet. Again thx :)

Comment: @user1079028 You could thank me by marking my answer as the correct one. I'm glad I could help ;)

Comment: I did, i tried before but it does not let me to mark it before some time passed ( i guess you know this).

Answer (score 0):

```
where s.pid=:pid and s.polid=p.polid"
```

You have a "=:" in a WHERE-Clause

```
WHERE S.PID = PID AND S.POLID = P.POLID
```

Maybe change your variable from PID to somthing like E_PID to mark it extern...

Comment: nope it is not a mistake, Tarec found the problem actually. Thansk though